# Using Random Math To Choose & Place An Image

Tags: javascript, math, random

New to JS and gamemaking and things.  I'm not sure I'm even really doing this right, but I'm using Phaser to make a HTML5/JS game.  At the start of the game I'd like for the code to generate three plots for farming, choosing between poor, normal, and good soil.

Now it's supposed to generate a number between 1 and 10 and then assign the soil to a place based on the returned value, 1 = poor, 2 - 8 = normal, 9 or 10 = good.  But I can't make it work, and I'm not sure what I have wrong.  Nothing happens when I try to run it and the background image doesn't even work.

The code I have so far is like so:

```
function create() {
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'startbg');
    plot1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);

    if ( plot1 === 1 ){
        game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'poor');
    }else if (plot1 >= 2 && plot1 <=8){
        game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'norm');
    }else (plot1 === 9 || plot1 === 10){
        game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'good');
    }
```

What have I done wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last `else` has a condition statement but isn't an `else if`. Try removing it and see if that works:

```
else {
    game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'good');
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, that worked for me.  I had no idea both had to be an else if.

Comment: No problem. You could have also used `else if (plot1 === 9 || plot1 === 10){` -- you just can't have the condition without "if."

Answer (score 1):

You can try this , although without seeing more of your code I doubt it will work, but maybe.

Also, so the `190, 250` ... are those coordinates for your background position for the sprite?  Sprites highest coordinate values are `0, 0`. So if they are, it should actually be `-190, -250` , and probably with a px at the end too, like `-190px, -250px`.

```
function create() {
    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'startbg');
    plot1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1);

    if ( plot1 === 1 ){
        game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'poor');
    }else if (plot1 >= 2 && plot1 <=8){
        game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'norm');
    }else if (plot1 === 9 || plot1 === 10){
        game.add.sprite(190, 250, 'good');
    }
    else {
        alert("some error");
    }
}
```